# How to make a decorator for defining required properties of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-decorators

I tried writing a decorator as such (going off memory, excuse any problems in code):

```
def required(fn):
    def wrapped(self):
        self.required_attributes += [fn.__name__]
        fn(self)

    return wrapped
```

and I used this to decorate @property attributes in classes, e.g.:

```
@property
@required
def some_property(self):
    return self._some_property
```

...so that I could do something like this:

```
def validate_required_attributes(instance):
    for attribute in instance.required_attributes:
        if not hasattr(instance, attribute):
            raise ValueError(f"Required attribute {attribute} was not set!")
```

Now I forgot that this wouldn't work because in order for the required_attributes to be updated with the name of the property, I would have to retrieve the property first. So in essence, when I do **init** in the class, I can just do a self.propertyname to add it... but this solution is not nice at all, I might as well create a list of required attribute names in the **init**.

From what I know, the decorator is applied at compile time so I wouldn't be able to modify the required_attributes before defining the wrapped function. Is there another way I can make this work? I just want a nice, elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `def __init__(self, required_one, required_two)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [attrs library](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) does what you want. You can define a class like this, where `x` and `y` are required and `z` is optional.

```
from attr import attrs, attrib

@attrs
class MyClass:
    x = attrib()
    y = attrib()
    z = attrib(default=0)
```

Testing it out:

```
>>> instance = MyClass(1, 2)
>>> print(instance)
MyClass(x=1, y=2, z=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take at doing it with a class decorator and a method decorator. There's probably a nicer way of doing this using metaclasses (nice being the API not the implementation  ;)).

```
def requiredproperty(f):
    setattr(f, "_required", True)
    return property(f)


def hasrequiredprops(cls):
    props = [x for x in cls.__dict__.items() if isinstance(x[1], property)]
    cls._required_props = {k for k, v in props if v.fget._required}
    return cls


@hasrequiredprops
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._my_prop = 1

    def validate(self):
        print("required attributes are", ",".join(self._required_props))

    @requiredproperty
    def my_prop(self):
        return self._my_prop
```

This should make validation work without the requiring the caller to touch the property first:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.validate()
required attributes are my_prop
>>> a.my_prop
1
```

The class decorator is required to make sure it has the required property names duing instantiation. The `requiredproperty` function is just a way to mark the properties as required.

That being said, I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here. Perhaps validation of the instance attribute values that the property should return?

Comment: I liked this answer. However, I had to make a small edit to support both @property and @requiredproperty on the same class: 

From `cls._required_props = {k for k, v in props if v.fget._required}` to => `cls._required_props = {k for k, v in props if '_required' in vars(v.fget) and v.fget._required}`

Otherwise, the lack of the `_required` in non required properties will make it fail.